# React state is getting updated when its assigned variable is changed or updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state `formData` in which `mappedColumn` is one of the object as below

```
const [formData, setFormData]=useState({
               mappedColumns:[
               {
                 source:"MAIN SOURCE",
                 target:"MAIN TARGET",
                 transformationValue:"MAIN VALUE"
               }
              ]
            })

var targetIndex = 0;
let mappingConfig = [...formData.mappedColumns];
var mIndex = mappingConfig.findIndex(function(p){ return p.target== targetIndex})
mappingConfig[mIndex].source = 'source';
mappingConfig[mIndex].transformationValue = 'value';
```

When I made any changes to the variable `mappingConfig` the actual state variable `formData.mappedColumns` is getting updated with whatever values are assigned  to `mappingConfig`. Why is it happening so. What is the soluion for this. Anyone please help !!

Comment: Can not understand your doubts. Just describe what you want to do and what you had do ?

Comment: @EricChao My state object formData.mappedColumns has values mappedColumns:[
               {
                 source:"MAIN SOURCE",
                 target:"MAIN TARGET",
                 transformationValue:"MAIN VALUE"
               }
              ]  
I am trying to uitilise it but not update and hence I have referred it to a variable and trying to update the refrred variable, but my actual state variable is getting updated, which should not happen, because I am not updating the state

Comment: I will post exact answer a litle later but replace  let mappingConfig = [...formData.mappedColumns] with  let mappingConfig = formData.mappedColumns.map((value) => ({ ...value }));

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
let mappingConfig = [...formData.mappedColumns];
```

use

```
let mappingConfig = formData.mappedColumns.map((value) => ({ ...value }));
```

This is because you need to destructure the exact object that is being updated. Otherwise it will still point to old reference

Answer (score 0):

You should use deep clone to copy a data typeof  Object

```js
//  let mappingConfig = [...formData.mappedColumns];
let mappingConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formData.mappedColumns))
```